# Msp fails as custom task of previous wix msi fails

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, msp

we are trying to create patch (.msp ) , but when we install it ,it did not update any files.

While we analyzed it , we found that there was custom task written in previous version of msi has defect in uninstall.

As it fails to uninstall, msp is not upgrading.

Now we can't change the previous msi as it was released to customer already.

Is there any way to make msp to install by having any workaround? Also we wanted to fix uninstall issue of previous custom task.

Answer (score 2):

Its hard to advise in detail as your problem is not well defined.

When you apply an msp the installed product will not uninstall. A patch is a transform to your installed msi then a repair.

It may be possible to fix the custom action and update it in the patch.